# By-pass Mobile Browser View panel on Mac

Tags: mobile, spo

I've been experiencing this lately and can't seem to figure out how to overcome this issue - Anytime that I make a update to a .txt file in the Site Assets library and the Web part will load and work on first load, but as soon as I refresh the page again, the 'Mobile Desktop View' pane pops up and you are unable to by-pass it even with a hard refresh/clear cache on Macs.

I know on my previous Windows, there was a button in the bottom right corner to exit the view, I can't find that anywhere on the Mac version. Does anyone have any knowledge on how I can get out of the mobile view?

[image]